# Friend's games counts to steam achievements percentage?

Tags: steam, achievements

I want to know if shared games with friends (or family like steam names it) counts to statistics on profile like average %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, achievements from shared games are included into your stats.

From community guide [How Average Game Completion Rate is Calculated](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=650166273):

> Rule #6: Shared Libraries ...
> Along the same lines of earning achievements for games that aren't actually attached to your account, Rule 3 seems to apply once again to games that you play using Steam's 'Shared Library' system.

> While I haven't been able to test this myself, it does make perfect sense to me that any achievements earned while you play someone else's games on a Shared Library will affect your AGCR.

Also [Steam Family Sharing announcement](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) hints that you get your own achievements by playing others games:

> Steam Family Library Sharing allows family members and their guests to play one another's games while earning their own Steam achievements ...