# Who counts as a "player", for Steam achievement percentages?

Tags: steam, achievements

For each Steam achievement, the platform gives statistics along the lines of "23.6% of players have this achievement". Who counts as a "player" for this calculation? (To put it another way, what is the denominator?)

It is relevant if you want to figure out how awesome you actually are.

For example, if "players" were defined as "anyone who has bought the game", then my achievement percentages compare me not only to people who have played the game, but also to those who haven't even downloaded it! Which means that my achievement is less impressive than one's initial intuitions might suggestion.

On the opposite end, you could define "players" as something like "anyone who has played the game for over an hour". Or perhaps "anyone who has played the game for at least as long as I have".

Maybe Valve answers this somewhere, but I couldn't find it easily.

Comment: Possibly somewhat related: [Friend's games counts to steam achievements percentage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/376261/80914) because players don't need to buy the game to get the achivements.

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

Recently discovered the game [Pinapple on Pizza](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2263010/Pineapple_on_pizza/), a free game which has an achievement for "Play" that had a 100% unlock.  At the time of testing, there were 2,668 reviews and the game had been out for approximately 9 hours.  I was unable to find a way to review a game I do not own, so it's safe to assume all those reviews have the game tied to their account, even if they may not have actually installed or started it.

Before adding to account, before installing, and after installing, the percentage for "Play" remained at 100%.  I started the game just to see how the achievement worked.  It does not unlock at the main menu, but rather after immediately after clicking "Play".  Without data on number of owners, installs, and starts, it's not possible to give an exact answer.  However, given how new the game is, it seems likely that a decent percentage of players would be installing or waiting to play it, and given the fact that user interaction is required to get the achievement, **it is probably safe to assume percentages are based on number of players that have actually started up the game**.

[image]

**Previous example, which has more data to work with**

Take a look at the game [Chime](https://store.steampowered.com/app/62100/Chime/), specifically the achievement [Fairy Godmother](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/Chime/achievements/).  It is awarded for starting up the game.  No user interaction required.  This achievement has a 98% global unlock.

Using data from [this article](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/07/steam-data-leak-reveals-precise-player-count-for-thousands-of-games/), Chime had roughly 106,325 players as of July 1, 2018.  This means either *at least* 2126 players had that achievement bugged, or Steam does not limit it to only players that have started the game.

While I've not done an exhaustive search, I attempted to find complaints for that achievement not triggering.  I was unable to find anything, and I'd think at least one of those 2k+ people would have mentioned it.

Comment: Does the game have some start-up menu before the main one? I'm thinking of a situation where one could get to that menu (which would tell Steam that you've started it up and thus are part of the achievement stats) but change their mind before actually opening up the game for some reason, which would perhaps not get them the achievement.

Comment: Another explanation for this could be that the achievement was added 'at some point' after the game was released, as per  [this comment](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/07/steam-data-leak-reveals-precise-player-count-for-thousands-of-games/?comments=1&post=35620447#comment-35620447) in the article referenced in the answer - The figures show "total number of Steam users who have played the game at least once after achievements were added to the game."

Comment: And the third (likely) explanation would be - some of those 2% might be people just "idling" trading cards (if the game has any ofc) via something like ArchiSteamFarm, which doesn't require to launch an actual game (thus triggering the achievement), yet makes Steam think that the game is launched (to count playtime), making it eligible for the stats.

Comment: My understanding, through similar achievements, has always been that the "players" are actually "people that own the game on steam"

Comment: For Steam, 98% of owners actually playing the game seems unusually high. Is it possible that 2% of players crashed at the loading screen?

Comment: Steam knows when a player launches a game through Steam, but it can't know if the game started *successfully*. A 2% quota of people who tried to launch the game but it wouldn't start / crashed before triggering the achievement seems plausible to me.

Comment: @DanM. Chime does not have trading cards at this point.

Comment: I agree with @user253751. If it were a freshly released AAA game like Cyberpunk 2077, 98% of owners playing the game wouldn't necessarily be odd. However, Chime looks like the kind of game many would've gotten as part of a bundle or for dirt cheap during some Steam Sale, without any particular intent to play it.

Comment: @user253751 I find it hard to believe that so many users would immediately crash and not post online about it.  I suppose another option could be that Steam only counts players that have downloaded the game.  That would mean some players downloaded it, but never started it up.

Comment: The game Walking Simulator 2020 has an achievement like so: "Successfully launch the game". It is sitting at 40.7% currently, so players who never launched the game are part of the data. It would be interesting to find out if a "player" needs to have installed the game to be counted as a player in the percentage for achievements which OP is asking for... For now, it's clear this % includes at least the players who haven't even launched the game. Maybe those who haven't even installed it, I think it makes sense cause you can uninstall and reinstall your games anyway.

Comment: @Manuki Walking Simulator's achievements were not available at the release of the game (see [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1214280/discussions/0/2263563948128412562/))

Comment: Some Steam games don't let you earn achievements while playing offline, which could also explain the 2% if Chime is such a game.